# Can I attribute my game to a game studio that isn't registered as an LLC, INC, etc

Tags: copyright, attribution

I asked a somewhat [related question over here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/119373/whose-name-should-i-put-next-to-my-copyright-notice).

There reason I want to attribute my game to a "random studio" is for the sole purpose of getting a domain with the same name as my studio and point everyone who is interested to go there and to let people know what I'm up to. My other option is to just grab a domain that has the same name as my game but I figured that might cost too much in the long run if I have to do that for every game I publish. I figured it might cost less if I just get a domain bearing my studio's name and add any future games I make as a subdomain.  (ie. mygame.mystudio.com)

Another option would be to just get a domain using my name but would http://mygame.johndoe.com look professional to look at?

But according to the responses I got from my first question, it would be nonsensical to attribute my game to a company that doesn't exist.

If my game generates any money, I do plan on registering the studio name attached to my game as an LLC,INC, etc. but right now, I can't really afford to do it.

Answer (score 1):

It would help to know what jurisdiction you're in. If you're in the United States, you can register a [DBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trade_name) *(Doing business as/Trade name)*

The fees for registering a DBA vary from state to state, but in general it costs very little (about $50 or less)

You can later file the paperwork to convert your DBA to an LLC with the same name, should you so desire.